# Article links from Joomla article do not work for multi-language website

Tags: joomla-3.x, articles, multilingual, weblinks

I have a Joomla article that contains links to other articles:

```
https://www.dev.gonativeguide.com/de/
```

I add the links with the "+article" button of the editor. My site is bilingual: English and German. When I add a link to an English article, the generated link works fine:

```
https://dev.gonativeguide.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=143&catid=38&lang=en-GB
```

However, when I add a link to a German article, the generated link does not work:

```
https://www.dev.gonativeguide.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=142&catid=38&lang=de-DE
```

> Error Code: 404 Article not found

The article not found can be accessed from the menu structure without any problems on the following link:

```
https://www.dev.gonativeguide.com/de/touren/budapest/142-budapest-stadtfuehrung-auf-deutsch
```

---

UPDATE: 
It seems that this is somehow not related to German, but the first language works the second language fails.

I also noticed that the generated URL is converted/redirected to a new URL that contains `/de` or `/en` after the domain name. It seems that for some reason **this `/de` or `/en` part is wrong and this causes the error:**

```
https://dev.gonativeguide.com/de/?option=com_content&view=article&id=143&catid=38&lang=en-GB
```

If I change `/de` to `/en` in the above link, it works.

Please also see the call stack below:

[image]

Any idea what may cause this and how to fix it?

Comment: Have you published Multilingual Status module for the Admin? It can give you very useful hints for your multilingual site settings.

Comment: As I checked it now, this links works for me on your site and resolved: `https://www.dev.gonativeguide.com/de/?option=com_content&view=article&id=142&catid=38&lang=de-DE`

Comment: As I see, you tried to use the english article `id` = `143` with your `de` menu link in your last example and it cannot be resolved. The german article `id` is `142` and has to have `/de` in the url also. In your first example link it is missing.

Comment: It looks like that your site now works correctly... :)

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at my site. As workaround I manually changed the generated url to the following for one of the links: https://www.dev.gonativeguide.com/de/?option=com_content&view=article&id=142&catid=38&lang=de-DE This way it works. It would be still interesting to know why the editor generated link cannot be correctly resolved.

Comment: Do you use Multilingual associations in creating your articles? Because for me in my site it works correctly embedding the correct link.

Comment: Yes, normally I do. I will double check if it is correctly set for the new articles as well and will let you know if it changes anything.